# Drawing a changing text obtained from a web service on a bitmap

Tags: android, bitmap

I am new to android app development. I am trying to develop an app which will obtain some data from a web service and i need to draw this on bitmap.But this text is not a constant text. It may change. Is it possible to draw such a changing text in bitmap? 
Kindly help me as i am new to this area.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide the code which has the problem.

Comment: Actually i am trying to develop an app based on augmented reality. I am using metaio sdk.So i need to display some text over a marker. This text i am getting from a web resource. But this is not a constant text. It is a changing text. So i have a doubt whether i can display such a changing text by drawing on a bitmap.?

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question, yes it is possible. However, your application will have to keep checking for any changes made, for them to be updated in the bitmap. It might not be too efficient. For web services, make sure you use a background process. (AsyncTask)

Comment: So how will i keep checking for the changes?. do i have to set any timer and access the web service when the timer expires everytime?.